# How to set action variable value from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

My code is like this:

```
public class CustoTypeAction extends ActionSupport{
   private ResultDto resultDto;
   //setter & getter resultDto
}
```

Config:

```
<action name="listCustoType" method="listCustomerType" class="custoType">
  <result name="success">listCustoType.jsp</result>
```

How can I set resultDto value to null from jsp on page load? What struts tag should I use?

Comment: by default it will be null, why do you think its not null ?

Comment: because i want the object shown only once, when user reload page again, the object = null

Comment: @mprabhat, for example the object is not null

Comment: @MahadiSiregar are you accessing this jsp directly ?

Comment: @mprabhat, i'm sorry i'm not understand what you mean. jsp will shown as controlled in struts.xml

Comment: I mean to say are you on reload are you directly calling /jsp/result.jsp or going via struts also is resultDto stored in session ?

Comment: going via struts and resultDto is not store on session,

Comment: please show how are you returning your jsp page, also it seems your page is being cached by browser

Comment: <action name="listCustoType" method="listCustomerType" class="custoType"><result name="success">listCustoType.jsp</result> ..

Comment: What is your use case for this? Why would you want it to be null the second time the user accesses the page?

Comment: @DaveNewton, ok Sir. Sorry,
i've solve it by using session. I remove the session when page load. I don't know if this the best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you must implement `Preparable` interface. It executes before `execute()` method.

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Preparable.html

If you want to show the object only once, and it must be gone after user reloads the page, you must use session. If file is snown already, you can change the value in session that it must not be shown on next reload.

You can see the example to work with session from here:

http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2-login.shtml